# VSCode terminal can't find NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

my VSCode (Win10) terminal is having issues when running NodeJs commands, such as `npm run start` (reactJs) or even `npm install`. I'm getting an error as if NodeJs was not in the $PATH as below. However, when I open the command prompt or powershell (without admin rights) the commands run normally.

Until yesterday it was working fine. Any ideas?

```
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error xbet-betfair@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the xbet-betfair@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Just to clarify, the files are were they are expected to be and, again, when I run them OUTSIDE VSCode everything works fine. The above is an example, but happens when a `npm install` requires to run a script to do an install too. For some reason, VSCode terminal can't find node.

Comment: Two things: Could you provide more terminal logs. Second: `node` is found that is why you get the error. Try `npm install --loglevel verbose`

Comment: Hi, for some reason I got it fixed by removing nodejs from the windows path, restarting and then adding it again. No uninstalls or anything else. Who knows....